# Setting up React classes to be compiled in Play

Tags: javascript, scala, reactjs, playframework

In my Play project, I added a simple React class to `/app/assets/js`:

```
var Question = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (<div>
      <p>{this.props.content}</p>
      <br>
      <p>{this.props.answer}</p>
    </div>);
  }
});
```

And I added the following to `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.webjars" % "react" % "0.14.7"
```

However, the JSX notation is still not recognised.

What else do I need to do to be able to use React in my Play project?

Comment: You should probably take a look at https://github.com/ddispaltro/sbt-reactjs. Server frameworks generally doesn't integrate asset-level (js\css) frameworks.

Comment: I added the plugin to my project and I enabled it but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: You should probably not enable it manually since `SbtWeb` is enabled by default within `Play`. From this point you `.jsx` files should be served as compiled `.js` ones if you haven't further transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a full and working Play 2.4 and React 0.14 sample project by [@ticofab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1003665/ticofab) here:

https://github.com/ticofab/play-scala-webjars-react

along with a blog post detailing all the steps needed:

http://ticofab.io/react-js-tutorial-with-play_scala_webjars/

which explains how to compile it all server-side using [sbt-reactjs](https://github.com/ddispaltro/sbt-reactjs) as you discussed with @Odomontois in the comments.

Comment: I added the plugin, the clean and compiled the project. When I run the project again, I get this on my first line of JSX notation `return (<div>Bla bla bla! Bla bla bla!</div>);` a compilation error saying:
`Unclosed regular expression.` I believe it still doesn't recognize the JSX notation.

Comment: Replace `<br>` with `<br />`

Comment: I changed the code from my original post to something more simple: `return (<div>Bla bla bla! Bla bla bla!</div>);`. Sorry for not clarifying

Comment: This file in `/app/assets/js`, what is the full file name including extension?

Comment: The name is `Dummy.js`

Comment: I'd rename it to `Dummy.jsx` with the `.jsx` extension.

Comment: If I do that, there are no more errors but it looks like the code isn't evaluated in any way.

Comment: That's great. You can add at the end of the `.jsx`: `React.render(<h1>Hello</h1>, document.getElementById('hello'));` - and, after adding `<div id="hello"></div>` in your HTML, you should see it rendered. That's assuming you include the compiled `.js` in the HTML.

Comment: I did exactly that but still the React rendering didn't have any effect. Since I am referencing the `jsx` file in my project like this: `<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("js/Dummy.js")'></script>`, I am assuming that it's not compiled. Which component is responsible with the compilation? The `sbt-reactjs` plugin?